# Problems in Video playback or quick scrolling problems - ThinkPad - Linux mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, mesa

I installed Linux Mint 20 on my laptop (thinkpad x1 yoga 4th gen | intel core i7 10th gen), I updated everything that needs to be updated through update manager, but when I open videos on YouTube or even those that exist on my computer while watching, black bars appear laterally ([video attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I3GIrG6ZMq_vhhpFK_DepjYfKG64UcEm/view?usp=sharing)). It also happens that I quickly scroll through an article in the browser or when i scroll in log files, the lines are smeared for a few moments and then return to their normal state.

Here is the screenshot video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I3GIrG6ZMq_vhhpFK_DepjYfKG64UcEm/view?usp=sharing

and this is the output from inxi -Fxz:

```
        System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana 
                   base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
        Machine:   Type: Convertible System: LENOVO product: 20SAS01X00 v: ThinkPad X1 Yoga 4th serial: <filter> 
                   Mobo: LENOVO model: 20SAS01X00 v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: N2QET27W (1.21 ) date: 06/09/2020 
        Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 13.3 Wh condition: 52.0/51.0 Wh (102%) model: LGC 02DL004 status: Discharging 
        CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-10710U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: N/A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
                   flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38399 
                   Speed: 700 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 701 2: 740 3: 769 4: 702 5: 712 6: 731 7: 710 8: 742 
                   9: 702 10: 701 11: 740 12: 705 
        Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
                   Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
                   OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) 
                   v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.0-devel (git-4d0e062 2020-07-21 focal-oibaf-ppa) direct render: Yes 
        Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: sof-audio-pci bus ID: 00:1f.3 
                   Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic 
        Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9462 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
                   IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
                   Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: Lenovo driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: efa0 bus ID: 00:1f.6 
                   IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter> 
        Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 47.77 GiB (10.0%) 
                   ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN730 SDBQNTY-512G-1001 size: 476.94 GiB 
        Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 47.76 GiB (10.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
        Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 54.0 C mobo: N/A 
                   Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 3015 
        Info:      Processes: 347 Uptime: 1h 36m Memory: 15.28 GiB used: 4.24 GiB (27.8%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
                   gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: zsh v: 5.8 inxi: 3.0.3
```

I tried to ask in several forums but got no answers. Hope you know how to help me here :)

Comment: It usually happens when I connect/disconnect a monitor after boot or change a display setting. Restarting the DE (i.e. Cinnamon) helped in most cases.

Comment: How to restart DE? you mean; sudo systemctl restart display-manager ?

Comment: I was pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`, but there may be some other ways [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143838/how-do-i-restart-cinnamon-from-the-tty).